# Se cambió el idioma de algunas partes en la plataforma de StackOverflow en Español

Tags: bug

Según lo que estoy viendo de un momento a otro pasó de estar todo en español que es lo correcto en esta plataforma a estar todo en inglés, ¿ocurrió algún tipo de bug o están haciendo algunas modificaciones? se me hace raro ya que no había pasado antes, o bueno, desde que estoy
[image]
[image]
Y en el meta también
[image]

Comment: Confirmo! hahaha... que extraño la verdad. Definitivamente es un error. Incluso Meta esta en Ingles tambien.

Comment: [Ya nuestros CM estan viendo el error](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51601579#51601579), gracias por reportar!

Comment: Todo esta en ingles.. con entrar al chat alcanzaba, me refiero a que para urgencias en el chat generalmente estamos mas atentos. Gracias por el aviso!

Comment: @gbianchi concuerdo, no es un tema que se pueda discutir o debatir aquí en Meta, de forma adecuada

Comment: Tranquilos, que si todo sale bien, este problema [ending mañana](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51601592#51601592)

Comment: volvimos volvimos volvimos!, dejen de correr en circulos!

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  ya se solucionó

Comment: @fedorqui no se te escapa nada!